# How to better modify global variable in async/multithreaded run

Tags: python

My dummy code below:

main.py:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from typing import List, Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Query, Body
import SERVER

app = FastAPI()

def get_flag(flag):
    SERVER.FindRequest(flag)
    return {}

async def handle_request(flag, loop, executor):
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, get_flag, flag)
    return result

@app.get('/get_flag')
async def get_data():
    test_required = [True, False, True, False]
    tasks = []
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    tasks = [handle_request(request, loop, executor) for request in test_required]
    processed_data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    executor.shutdown()
    return {}
```

SERVER.py

```
import DB

def FindRequest(flag=False):
    print('flag', 'DB.DB_MODE')
    print(flag, DB.DB_MODE)
    if (flag == True):
        DB.DB_MODE = 0
    print('flag', 'DB.DB_MODE')
    print(flag, DB.DB_MODE)
    return {}
```

DB.py

```
DB_MODE = 1
```

In the code above, I assume DB_MODE to be 0 only when flag is True, but, in first iteration DB_MODE become 0 and is then set as 0. How can I handle this better?

Comment: I read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728640/modify-global-variable-from-async-function-in-python

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function

Comment: You present some code that doesn't work (presumably?) and ask how to improve it - but you don't say what is actually wrong with it, or even what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @MarkSetchell: So, I would want the global variable value is not shared across threads. So, when flag is True it should be 0 and when flag is False it should be 1. Not happening in present snippet.